# <ImageButton> con dos líneas de texto

Tags: android-studio, botón

Tengo puesto un botón con una imagen de fondo, y me gustaría poner dos líneas de texto en el botón como el ejemplo de esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe si se pueden poner dos líneas y con el texto diferente color?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar usando un diseño como un botón creando con un `LinearLayout` con sus respectivos `Textview`, por separado, y personalizando el mismo de acorde al diseño que necesites, justo así (ejemplo sencillo):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/customButtonLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:text="First" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000">
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView" 
        android:text="Second"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

En la clase donde necesitas llamarlo o mostrarlo lo implementas de esta manera:

```
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"ARIALN.TTF") ;   
Typeface font2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "COMPCTAN.TTF");

TextView firstTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
TextView secondTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondTextView);

firstTextView.setTypeface(font);
secondTextView.setTypeface(font2);

LinearLayout btnLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.customButtonLayout);
btnLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Colocándole un `setOnClickListener` para convertirlo básicamente en un botón, y acá en `getAssets(),"ARIALN.TTF"` puedes colocar la fuente que desees en caso de que quieras que la fuente de un `TextView` sea diferente al otro.

También podrías hacer algo así para mejorar el diseño del mismo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="30dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="firstword"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="secondword"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Aca el `res/drawable/background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#d0d0d0" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke android:color="#202020" android:width="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

Este ejemplo también puedes probarlo implementando un `RelativeLayout`, es cuestión de que uses el que mas te acomode para lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias David, voy a intentarlo, la verdad que no me esperaba tener que utilizar tanto código para poner una linea mas de texto.

Comment: Hola @David ahora si puedo ver mejor y probarlo, antes desde el móvil no podía ver bien, lo he probado, pero lo malo es que veo que no puedo utilizar una imagen de fondo, y es lo que voy utilizando, poder poner una imagen como fondo del botón y escribir encima.

Comment: @SoCu intenta usar un `RelativeLayout` en vez de un `LinearLayout`

Comment: Ahora si, de todas formas voy a utilizar `ConstraintLayout` y lo que no consigo es que con `android:gravity="center"` el texto salga centrado dentro del botón, y lo que no me va a dar tiempo de probarlo ahora es ver en el código que tengo lo voy a poder utilizar sin contar con las propiedades que tienen los botones como en `public void onClick(View v) ...... case R.id.btn_uno:  `

Comment: Al final ha podido probarlo, pero al poner dentro del onCreateView me muestra un error http://funkyimg.com/i/2RgVa.png y la fuente tambien http://funkyimg.com/i/2Rh4m.png, ahora lo estoy utilizando en una clase `Fragment`

Comment: que error te da? @SoCu

Comment: Fallo mio de no ponerte el error cuando te capture las imagenes, esto es lo que muestra http://funkyimg.com/i/2Ri2A.png

Comment: @SoCu estas haciendo mal el llamado de las `view` desde el `fragment`, normalmente en `fragments` se llama distinto a un `Activity` común, te invito a que leas un poco la documentación de [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es-419.)

Comment: Quite el error, pero cuando se inicia la aplicación se cierra tiran un error **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference** Para ver que estoy haciendo mal, he intentado buscar un VideoTutorial pero todos son en una Clase Activity, no he visto ninguno en Clase Fragment.